# How can one set the size of an igraph plot?

Tags: python, r, plot, igraph

I'm currently plotting my graphs like this:

```
        ig.plot(graph, target=file, vertex_color=membership,
            vertex_label=[index for index, value in enumerate(graph.vs)],
            vertex_frame_width=0,
            palette=ig.ClusterColoringPalette(len(set(membership)) + 3))
```

The plot is output to a PDF file on a single page. It looks decent but the nodes are too crowded. Is there a way to pull the nodes apart so that I can actually see all the edges? I was thinking of increasing the size of the plot but I don't know how to do that.

Here's how it looks right now: [image: current plot]

Comment: You mean setting the edge width? How would that help?

Comment: on second thoughts use layout  options to set the size of the box

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From thie python [igraph tutorial](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Layout objects also contain some useful methods to translate, **scale** or rotate the coordinates in a batch. However, the primary utility of Layout objects is that you can pass them to the plot() function along with the graph to obtain a 2D drawing

```
visual_style = {}
visual_style["layout"] = g.layout()
visual_style["bbox"] = (300, 300)
visual_style["margin"] = 10
plot(g, **visual_style)
```

Comment: After trying out various layouts and transformations, I settled on layout_kamada_kawai. Setting the right bbox (ie: 1024x1024) helps a lot to pull nodes apart. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexG. happy to help! :) glad you find one to suit.